# ImageMagick Append Recursive Subdirectories via CMD prompt

Tags: cmd, imagemagick

I have a large group of folders inside of a root folder. I want to -append each of the images in each subfolder into one large image.

Start:
Folder 1\1.tif
Folder 1\2.tif
Folder 1\3.tif
Folder 1\4.tif
Folder 2\1.tif
Folder 2\2.tif

Output:
Folder 1\Combined.tif
Folder 2\Combined.tif

I tried a code line like:

```
magick FOR /R *.tif -append Combined.tif
```

How do I get recursive subfolders to work for an -append for ImageMagick, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try this at the moment, but I think if you do:

```
DIR /S /B *.TIF > FILES.TXT
```

you will get a list of files, unadorned with sizes and stuff.

You should then be able to pass this to **ImageMagick** with:

```
magick @FILES.TXT -append result.tif
```

It may even work without an intermediate file:

```
DIR /S /B *.TIF | magick @- -append result.tif
```

Comment: The switches (`/S /B`) may need to come after `*.TIF`.

Comment: Thank you1 That's pretty cool, I didn't know I can save the file names like that. It's very helpful.

Do you know if there's a way to get it to do each SubDirectory uniquely?

Comment: Sure, `DIR SUB1 /S /B` and `DIR SUB2 /S /B`